# AWS Step Functions architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

In my organization we are planning to implement state machine and workflow for some product. I liked the concept of Step Functions and tried to implement it in my project. However there are some customization which I need and some restriction due to which I want to design my own workflow engine.

1. Which datastore and data structure do they use to store these workflows?
2. How they are managing workflow properties like which action is in parallel, retries on actions, try exceptions etc.

Comment: AWS typically does not release information about the "inner workings" of their services.

Comment: yes, my intention for asking these questions was the same. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A lot of this can be found by just looking at the documentation:

1. All Step functions are written in JSON: [Amazon States Language - AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-amazon-states-language.html)
2. If you want Lambda functions to run in parallel it is possible to control:
   [Parallel - AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html)

For error handling and retries: [Error Handling - AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html)

I'd recommend opening and playing around with the AWS step functions service - they have some great pre-made samples which give you a working insight into each of these concepts.